Desktop app not working on sqflite_common_ffi on creating the build
When you encounter issues with sqflite_common_ffi not working after creating a build for a Flutter desktop application, the problem often relates to how the SQLite database is initialized and accessed on different platforms. Here’s a common solution based on similar issues seen on platforms like Stack Overflow:
The sqflite_common_ffi package works well during development, but after building the application (e.g., creating an .exe or .msix for Windows), the app fails to interact with the SQLite database

I tried creating the build again and again
added sqlflite.dl
